# Logitech Brio 4K no microphone sound in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, logitech, pipewire

I have bought a Logitech Brio 4K camera which is running fine out of the box as a webcam but I can't get the microphone to work reliably. I'm on Ubuntu 23.04 and the camera is plugged using an USB port on my computer.

I can always see the device in the sound settings but it's just not getting any sound through.

I have tried lots of things, one of them was to enable Pipewire. I managed, once, to get the microphone to work by deleting the folder `./.config/pulse/` and logging out and back in.

Since then, I turned my computer off and it's not working anymore, deleting the folder doesn't solve it anymore either.

I have also tried changing everything I could in pavucontrol but it doesn't work, no matter which settings I put.

I really don't know where to look for anymore so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some info from the terminal:

```bash
# lsusb -d "0x046d:"
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:086b Logitech, Inc. Logi 4K Stream Edition

$ LANG=C pactl info | grep '^Server Name'
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.65)

$ pactl list short sources
55  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
56  alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
518 alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor    PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
843 alsa_input.usb-046d_Logi_4K_Stream_Edition_8726A05C-03.analog-stereo    PipeWire    s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```